# Add new values to Enum and set them to true by default [Flags]

Tags: c#, enum-flags

I have a enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Role
{
    Basic = 0,
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4,
    D = 8
}
```

I store this value to DB in `int` column `Role` where `Role = A | B | C` (for example), so I'm using bitwise operators.

I add 2 new values to this enum: `E = 16` and `F = 32`.
But I need to set these values to true by default for old DB records.

One way I see how to implement this - DB migration where `Role = old Role value + 16 + 32`. Is it correct?

And is there an other way to implement this?

Comment: I don't think you can expand enums in code, if that's what you are asking..

Comment: He's trying to add the values in the DB, not in c#.

Comment: You can 'OR' Enumeration bits together when the values do not overlap.  You are using Power of 2 for you values so you do not have any overlap.  So doing Role = A | B | C is acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your enum has values as power of twos, your suggestion seems to be working and it's safe to assume that you can use it.

Some DB providers do have bitwise operations though, e.g:

- Mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-or